# What is __attribute__ vector_size?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc-extensions

Given this code:

```
using vec = uint32_t __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
```

How can it be rewritten for MSVC 2015?

Comment: Probably `__m128`, we can't see you using it.

Answer (score 4):

It's a GCC specific extension for creating integer & float types that are larger than 64 bits, and as far as I know there is no direct replacement in VC++, but there is an __m128d type that you may be able to use instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is an example of the [gcc vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) which are an abstraction over the SIMD instructions.

This particular line creates a type alias `vec` for a vector that is a total of 16 bytes long, and consists of 32 bit sized unsigned itegers.

MSVC doesn't appear to have an equivalent extension. The use of SIMD is supported through [alignment routines and inline assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01fth20w(v=vs.80).aspx). As such, there is no way to exactly rewrite the line and it is not sufficient to rewrite just *this line*, but also the lines where the alias or objects using the type, are used.

Comment: MSVC provides the [__m128i](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26232t5c.aspx) data type with equivalent layout to that the OP is looking for. Variables of type `__m128i` are also suitably aligned on 16-byte boundaries. The SIMD instructions are supported through [compiler intrinsics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx). The x64 compiler doesn't support inline assembly, and inline assembly is not the recommended way to implement SIMD code.